# Is there any php-ga ports to Ruby on Rails

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm looking for RoR solution to register direct redirects from my site, php-ga looks good but it is PHP.

I mean I have some `controller#redirect` action which makes smth like this

```
def redirect
  link = Links.find_by_key params[:key]

  redirect_to link.url
end
```

That makes flawless redirects from `http://myurl.com/XXX` to target location for any external references.

I definitely do not want to use real redirect page with JS code. And PHP-GA ( http://code.google.com/p/php-ga/ )  looks like the only prod-level and documented solution to register visits in Google Analytics directly from controller, but it's on PHP.

So, I return to my original question: *Is there any php-ga ports to Ruby on Rails?*

Answer (score 0):

i did not really understand what your exact question is, but if you are looking for a ruby implementation of a google analytics client library, you could have a look at garb https://github.com/vigetlabs/garb

Comment: I'm asking about registering `visit` in GA from controller (e.g. server side), not view (e.g. client side). And I do not see that GARB can do this, it looks like more for reporting, not registering visitors

Answer (score 0):

Seems to have been abandoned last year, but try `gabba`, it probably still works: https://github.com/hybridgroup/gabba